# $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{N}\setminus\Omega}\vert x-z\vert^{-N-\alpha} dz = c \ \forall x\in\partial U$ implies $dist(x,\partial\Omega)=c, x \in \partial U$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, measure-theory, integration

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb R_+$, $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^N$ and $U \subset \Omega$. Is it true that if
$$\int_{\mathbb R^N \setminus \Omega} |x - z|^{-N-\alpha} dz = \text{constant} \quad \text{for all $x \in \partial U$}$$
then $\mathrm{dist}(x, \partial \Omega) = \text{constant}$ for all $x \in \partial U$?

I have a guess that the statement is true if $\Omega $ is a ball, but I don't know how to prove it or how to address the general case.

Note that this integral was estimated in the related question  [Prove $\int_{\mathbb R^N \setminus \Omega} |x - z|^{-N-s} dz \approx dist(x,\partial \Omega)^{-s}$, $s \in (0,2)$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391031/prove-int-mathbb-rn-setminus-omega-x-z-n-s-dz-approx-distx-par)

Comment: $\operatorname{dist}(\partial U, \partial \Omega)$ is just a number, cannot be constant. :-) In general, the level sets of the integral do not coincide with the level sets of the distance to boundary.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Thanks! And sorry: I meant to write $\mathrm{dist}(x, \partial \Omega) = c$ for all $x \in \partial U$ instead.

Comment: I would remove the two subtractions, asking this instead as "Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^N$, $U\subset \Omega$, $\alpha+N<0$. Is it true that if $\int_\Omega |x-z|^\alpha dz \ldots$"

Comment: @MattF. What do you mean?